# Amazon EC2: How can I monitor that my software is running?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I run a server application on an amazon EC2 Instance. As such it must always be running. IN the case that it does crashes, I need to know right away.

Is there a simple way in which I can monitor that my server application is running, and trigger some action when it no longer runs? (Like running a script that sends me an email)

Answer (score 0):

You can use monit(https://mmonit.com/monit/), its very easy to setup and configure the monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, but I've allready solved it by actually implementing my own monitor as another application